# Get first and last day of month into variables - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I would like to declare some variables that contain the first and last date of the current month in Oracle. I know how to get these values, but evidently not store or use them; I am more of a T-SQL guy.

In T-SQL, I could write:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = GETDATE();
DECLARE @endDate DATE = EOMONTH(GETDATE());

SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate;
```

I cannot, for the life of me, work out how to do this in Oracle. I have tried several variations, like:

```
DECLARE END_DT DATE := TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))
END_DT DATE := TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE))

DECLARE END_DT DATE;
SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) INTO END_DT FROM DUAL;
```

I am mostly using 11g, but I would like to be able to use the same script on a 9i/10g server also.

Comment: I think a simple google search can return you with required result. See https://www.mandsconsulting.com/first-and-last-day-of-month-oracle-sql-syntax-examples/

Comment: @XING I’m guessing you didn’t read my post fully.

Comment: Your text and the T-SQL contradict each other. `getdate()` gets the current date (and time) not the first day of the current month. Which one do you really want?

Comment: @stickybit that was just an example. Didn’t want to write dateadd.... etc.

Comment: @TaylorN  You can use `BEGIN` and `END` after `DECLARE` to store values in variable. As you mentioned you have the queries to get first and last day, just use the block to assign the variable as shown in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use such a query to detect first and last days of the current month :

```
SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)))+1,
       TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)) 
  INTO :startDate,:endDate 
  FROM DUAL;
```

with the contribution of [`ADD_MONTHS()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php) function

**Update** : Alternatively use this PL/SQL code block :

```
DECLARE
  startDate date;
  endDate   date;
BEGIN
 startDate := TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)))+1;
 endDate   := TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)); 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('startDate :  '||startDate); 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('endDate :  '||endDate);  
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=437ad95054247ce64dbf399ff97eacd0)</kbd>

Comment: If I run this in Toad, I get prompted to provide values for the variables, I just left them null, but then get an error "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number". If I run in SQL Developer, I get another error: "ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist"

Comment: I prefer using a product called PL/SQL Developer of AllRoundAutomations firm. In which I'm able to see the first SQL well, as appears in the demo fiddle. For your case, you can try the second one @TaylorN .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAST_DAY` and `TRUNC` combination as following:

> ```
> DECLARE
>     START_DT   DATE := TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM');
>     END_DT     DATE := TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE));
> BEGIN
> --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(START_DT || '   ' || END_DT);
>     SELECT
>         *
>     INTO <...>
>     FROM
>         SOMETABLE
>     WHERE
>         SOMEDATE BETWEEN START_DT AND END_DT;
>
> END;
> /
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: When I run this, I get an error: "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

Comment: That is just an idea. You can see updated answer now

Comment: I believe the error is referring to selecting into a variable.

Comment: Yes you are right but your issue of finding the first and last day of the month is properly highlighted in the answer.!!

Comment: That’s not my issue. Read the question again.

Comment: And usage of them is also highlighted via query. Dont DV it. We are here to help you out.